# Delete row in database using angular js

Tags: php, angularjs

I want delete when click in button , but my code not work . Here is my code
html

```
<tr class="row" ng-repeat="data in vm.mydata >
                <td class="col-md-1"> <span>{{data.masp}}</span></td>
                <td class="col-md-1"> <span>{{data.hangsx}}</span></td>
        </tr>
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-2x" aria-hidden="true" ng-click="vm.delete(data.masp)"></i>
```

angular

```
function dsController($http){
        var vm =this;
$http.get('/project/app/server/data/data.php')
             .then(onSuccess);

        function onSuccess(response){
            vm.mydata = response.data.records;
        } 
vm.delete = function(value){
            $http({
                method:'POST',
                url:'/project/app/server/action/xoa.php',
                data:({value:value}),
                headers : { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            }).then(onSuccess,onError);
            function onSuccess(){
            $http.get('/project/app/server/data/data.php')
                .then(function(data){
                    vm.mydata = data.data.records;
                })
}
```

and here is php code : xoa.php

```
    //connect db
    if(!empty($_POST['value'])){
    $masp = $_POST['value'];
    $sql = "DELETE FROM sanpham WHERE masp= '$masp'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
   if($result){
  echo 'OK';
```

}
data.php

```
$rows = array();
if($result){
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}
print '{"records":' .json_encode($rows) ."}";
```

Where is my wrong . Pls help me

Comment: Why are you making an HTTP POST request for deleting an object? You should use HTTP DELETE.

Comment: is data getting removed from the table

Comment: Your above code seems fine. Can you please share the error if you are getting any? Or please confirm from db table that record deleted or not?

Comment: I think you forgot to add this line which you added just now?

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

Comment: I change to delete but not work to . and data not remove from the table , and no error

Comment: @MaheshSinghChouhan sr it's my false because not coppy all . i have this lnie in my code

Comment: It's ok. Please use "error_reporting(E_ALL);"  at top of your data.php and please check again is there any error is coming up?

Comment: yes . I have use it but no error

Comment: Please echo $sql and try to run query directly into your db and check record is getting deleting or not?

Comment: Its not delete in database . Could you write simple example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In html you add

```
vm.delete(data.masp,$index)
```

in js you change

```
vm.delete = function(value,index)
{
method:'GET',
url:'/project/app/server/data/data.php?value=' +value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this :

```
                               vm.delete  = function (value) {
                                    var Response = $http({
                                        method:'POST',
                                            url:'/project/app/server/action/xoa.php',
                                            data:{value: JSON.stringify(value)},
                                    });
                                    return Response;
                                }
```